# How to prevent odd scrollbar flash?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I don't think what I am doing is all that unusual, but I'm certainly getting an unusual result.

I have a normal UITableView, and when one of the cells is touched, I push a viewController onto the navigationController stack. Nothing I have not done 100 times before.

This particular viewController is another UITableViewController, with one section, and one cell. This one cell contains a UITextView. It's a totally generic "Enter your notes" screen. This screen sets the UITextView to be the firstResponder in viewDidAppear.

The problem is this... as the new keyboard is sliding on to the screen, over the new viewController... I get something that looks suspiciously like a "scrollbar flash" only it's on the LEFT side of the screen. The effect is that I have a dot flash in the upper left hand corner of my screen. I can reproduce this in both the simulator and the device.

[weird dot http://matthewcave.com/images/weird_dot.png](http://matthewcave.com/images/weird_dot.png)

I can post code, but I was wondering if someone had seen this before, and had a quick answer as to how I could make it go away. If I were to post code, what would you want to see? Posting the whole viewController class seems like overkill, but I literally have no idea where the problem is.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I have just encountered this issue, the forum post at http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=763919 gives one solution, to inherit from UIViewController and make your own table view, but I'd like to know why this is happening.

Comment: I never did solve this. I didn't see your above referenced article, but that is exactly what I did. Refactored the whole UITableViewController into a UIViewController that LOOKED like a table view. If I encounter it again, I'll come back, edit the question with more info, and try again to find a solution.

Comment: That would be great. I want to keep things simple, so subclassing UITableViewController is the easiest thing to do; it's a shame it might have a few bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if that is a table or section header that is sized very small?

Comment: it flashes and goes away, it looks exactly like the "scrollbar flash" but I cannot figure out why it is on the left.

Comment: Is there a tiny table 0px wide on the left side someplace? :-)  Maybe if you crate the table with a CGRectZero?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this while desperately trying to find a work around. I had the idea that I would change the scrollbar color to white (at least temporarily, to make it less visible). But I found that no mater if it is set to white or black, as long as the color is forced, you won't see the dot. I wish I had a further explanation, but this is by far the simplest fix out there.

```
//configure tableview behavior
self.tableView.rowHeight = 178.0f;
self.tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite; //hide the scrollbar dot
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```